# Is it possible to create implementable er diagram in oracle apex

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, entity-relationship, diagram

Is it possible to create er diagram in oracle apex website?

[oracle apex website[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BOLbw.png)

Answer (score 0):

Nope, as far as I can tell. You'd need some kind of a tool which is capable of creating ERD based on tables in your schema. There's none on apex.oracle.com, and you can't access that database from "outside".

If you installed Oracle database on your own computer, as well as [SQL Developer Data Modeler](https://www.oracle.com/database/sqldeveloper/technologies/sql-data-modeler/download/), then you'd be able to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Not out of the box, but... you can reference javascript libraries and create custom html in a region so pick the javascript library of your choice and implement in an apex app. Pretty sure it is achievable.